# required: variable, found value - sorting a database

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
static void sort (Textbook [ ] info, int numEntries)
{
    long tempIsbn = 0;
    String tempTitle = "";
    String tempAuthor = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) //sorts the array
    {
        int minPos = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numEntries; j++)
        {
            if ( info [minPos].getIsbn() > info [j].getIsbn())
            {
                minPos = j;
            } //end if
            if (i < minPos)
            {
                tempIsbn = info [i].getIsbn();
                info [i].getIsbn() = info [minPos].getIsbn();
                info [minPos].getIsbn() = tempIsbn;

                tempTitle = info [i].getTitle();
                info [i].getTitle() = info [minPos].getTitle();
                info [minPos].getTitle() = tempTitle;

                tempAuthor = info [i].getAuthor();
                info [i].getAuthor() = info [minPos].getAuthor();
                info [minPos].getAuthor() = tempAuthor;

            } //end if

        } //end for
    } //end for
} //end sort
```

I am trying to sort the database and I get the error when I try to compare the first value to the second value. From what I understand the `info [i].getAuthor();` is a call to an object class but shouldn't it return a value? I guess I'm wondering why I am getting these errors cause it should be comparing two numbers?

This is my code for my object classes.

```
    public long getIsbn ( )
{
            return this.isbn;
}

    public String getTitle ( )
{
    return this.title;
}

public String getAuthor ( )
{
    return this.author;
}
```

These are some of the erros im getting.

```
    TextbookTracker.java:156: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
        info [i].getIsbn() = Long.parseLong (isbnInput);
                        ^
    TextbookTracker.java:161: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
        info [i].getTitle() = titleInput;
                         ^
    TextbookTracker.java:166: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
        info [i].getAuthor() = authorInput;
                          ^
    TextbookTracker.java:264: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
                info [i].getIsbn() = info [minPos].getIsbn();
                                ^
    TextbookTracker.java:265: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
                info [minPos].getIsbn() = tempIsbn;
                                     ^
    TextbookTracker.java:268: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
                info [i].getTitle() = info [minPos].getTitle();
                                 ^
    TextbookTracker.java:269: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
                info [minPos].getTitle() = tempTitle;
                                      ^
    TextbookTracker.java:272: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
                info [i].getAuthor() = info [minPos].getAuthor();
                                  ^
    TextbookTracker.java:273: unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value
                info [minPos].getAuthor() = tempAuthor;
                                       ^
    9 errors
```

Comment: You don't `compare` - you try to set a value... use `==` for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
 TextbookTracker.java:156: unexpected type
 required: variable
 found   : value
    info [i].getIsbn() = Long.parseLong (isbnInput);
```

how can you assign a value to a value? On the left side of assignment operator, you need a variable, while here it is a method call which returns a value

Comment: +1. Java does not do that (some languages do, they call it *lvalues*).

Comment: One more thing: if you want your class to be mutable, design setter methods.

Comment: @Thilo, thanks, I'm curious to know any example of those language :)

Comment: In Perl, you can do `substr($names, 5, 4) = "Mary";`, which *changes* the string so that the substring from index four becomes "Mary"